# Why does it keep it in the list?

Tags: python

```
def test(x,theList): 
    theList.append(x) 
    if x < 2: 
        x = x + 1 
        test(x,theList) 
        print x 
        print theList 

test(1,[])
```

Why is the result [1,2]? And not only [1]?

Comment: I deleted my answer because on rereading the code, I'm no longer sure what you are asking. The function doesn't return anything and the list you pass in isn't accessible after it returns. So, what do you mean when you say, "the result"?

Comment: I don't understand when he goes 1 deeper he change the list. But because I don't return it or something , why does it print [1,2]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you execute the `print` statement after the recursive call to `test()` returns.

Python objects are always passed by reference, so when the second invocation of test calls `theList.append(x)`, it is appending to the original list that was passed in, which is what you then print.

Comment: Ah ok I see, is there a way to let it not edit the orginal list?

Comment: @BBAA: You can call `test(x, theList[:])` which passes a copy of the list rather than the original. This is dicey, however; without knowing the real-world problem you are tackling, it's difficult to imagine under what circumstances such grossly inefficient code would be necessary.

Comment: Thank you Marcelo Cantos, you gave me all the information I needed to continue

Answer (score 0):

```
def test(x,theList): 
    if x < 2: 
        theList.append(x) 
        x = x + 1 
        test(x,theList) 
        print x 
        print theList 

test(1,[])
```

Comment: Yeah ok, but this is a test the real situation is different. I want to know why it change the list with out me returning to change the list?

Comment: @BBAA I can't understand what do you mean.